# protecting from race condition for primitive types in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

In turning on the ThreadSanitizer in Xcode, I think I see there have been some data race conditions regarding some of our primitive types that I'm trying to clean up.  Since we cannot use `@synchronized` for primitive types, is it best to do something like:

```
// declared somewhere in initialization
myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.comp.myqueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

// setter example for level that is a primitive type
dispatch_sync(self.myQueue, ^{
  _level = someValue;
});

// getter example
- (double) level {
  __block double result;
  dispatch_sync(self.myQueue, ^{
       result = _level
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why not make your `level` property `atomic`? That will at least guarantee you won't get garbage. But if you need to ensure there can only be one read / one writer at any given time, then the queue works. But consider using a concurrent queue with barrier sync for writing. This allows concurrent reading but writing must be done alone.

Comment: @rmaddy you are right that would be a solution. Problem is there is more validation logic in the setter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears correct, although I didn't test it specifically. You can also simply synchronize code blocks on another object within a property getter and setter. `_testDoubleLock` is a once initialized NSObject property:

```
NSObject * _testDoubleLock = @"_testDoubleLock";
double _testDouble;

-(double)testDouble {
    @synchronized(_testDoubleLock) {
        return _testDouble;
    }
}

-(void)setTestDouble:(double)testDouble
{
    @synchronized(_testDoubleLock) {
        _testDouble = testDouble;
    }
}
```

Comment: but can't you only do that on object types not primitive types?

Comment: I think you can as long as you have both a user defined getter and setter. You don't have to expose the setter in the header if you don't want, but even then should always use it to set the property inside the object to synchronize it. I'll update the code with an example.